# Virtual Box- Accidentally deleted vmdk file. What can I do?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

Hope someone can help me here. Really need to get back to work.

This morning my 120gb macbook air was filling up and I was prompted to remove some files. I had been playing around with Kali this week on another vm so decided to remove that to continue working on my Laravel apps. Unfortunately in a morning haze I deleted the wrong file :D

I am using virtual box + vagrant to run a Laravel development environment with Homestead
laravel [.] com/docs/5.4/homestead

Thankfully all my files are saved locally and mirrored on the vm so everything should be okay right?

When I try to 'vagrant up' and power on the vm I get error VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND opening image file '/Users/user/VirtualBox VMs/homestead-7/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) - the one I stupidly deleted. Lesson learned.

Inside the Virtual Box GUI -> homestead-7 (name of the machine) -> settings -> storage -> Controller SATA controller. Should I remove the reference to the deleted file and create a new one? Or should I delete this vm entirely and make a new one?

Can anyone tell me what to do? Would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data in vagrant not deleted, but database files deleted (ex. MySQL), You have to reinstall vagrant by delete machine from virtualbox [image: How to delete machine]

Then open Terminal

```
mv ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml ~/Homestead.yaml
rm -rf ~/Homestead
cd ~
cd Homestead
git checkout v5.4.0
mv ~/Homestead.yaml ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml
vagrant up
```

Hope that will work with you

Comment: You are welcome, you should remove Homestead folder in home directory and Machine in virtualbox. as I write in answer you should remove ~/Homestead folder to make sure you have fresh copy of homestead but we move your configuration in this line "mv ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml ~/Homestead.yaml"

Comment: Brilliant. Also before git checkout the user should run $ git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead and before vagrant up the user should rename / delete the 'homestead-7' folder in /Users/User/VirtualBox VMs/ so vagrant up can create a new vm. Thanks for the help!! And I also got an extra 30gb space and it's working! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

If you have created the box using `vagrant` you should also removed it using `vagrant`.

The command is:

```
vagrant destroy
```

and, besides the complete removal of the virtual machine (that includes also other files than the `.vmdk` file you removed by mistake), it also cleans up the files that Vagrant uses to access and manage the box.

Read more about [`vagrant destroy`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy.html) command in the documentation or type `vagrant help destroy` in your Terminal for a quick reminder of its command line argument.

---

Regarding the deleted `.vmdk` file, probably the only way to recover it is from the backup (Time Machine) assuming it is activated and you didn't configure it to ignore the "VirtualBox VMs" directory (as I did on my computer :-)).

Comment: Thanks!!! `vagrant destroy` works perfectly, this solution keeps all of your vagrant config files. After, just use `vagrant up` to re-download the os img

Comment: Simply `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` did the trick as @NickyKouffeld said